# Pause music while screen is locked

Tags: screen-lock, music-player

I was wondering whether it is possible to pause a music player (in my case Rhythmbox), by pressing a button, while the screen is locked. I would assume no, but I thought I'd ask.

A short example:
If the screensaver goes on the music continues. But lets say somebody comes in my office, I don't want to type in the password, but just hit a button to pause it. And ideally of course play again once I'm alone.

Is there a program that would allow something like this? I'm using Fedora16.

Edit thanks to pbm for the solution. Here is my `actkbd.conf` (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

```
25+29+56:::su MyUserName -c "dbus-send --type=method_call  --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.UPnP.MediaServer2.Rhythmbox /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause"
```

Comment: I find the question slightly ambiguous (as, maybe, did the previous commenter): do you want "when screensaver goes on, music pauses; when screensaver goes off, music resumes" or "screensaver goes on, but allows a certain scope of commands to be run, such as manipulating a media player" (a sort of party mode, if you will)?

Comment: Okay I see why there was a confusion. I updated it with a short example which should illustrate what my question is. So yes I'm looking for a sort of "party mode".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe there is easier solution for this, but my first guess was to use [actkbd](http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~thkala/projects/actkbd/) - keyboard (but not only) shortcut daemon that works outside of X server.

In config file you can bind any keys combination to any command. More details about running actkbd you can find in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4477/2661).

Rhythmbox can be controlled over dbus interface, so if you bind that command to some key it change your track.

```
dbus-send --type=method_call  --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox  /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
```

To discover more dbus "commands" you can use [d-feet](http://live.gnome.org/DFeet).

Comment: That doesn't look too bad. Unfortunately I'm really busy today, but I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: actkbd looks pretty neat.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and correct answer.