# how to force X mouse pointer to show above rendered application cursor?

Tags: xorg, mouse

I opened a new X session at :1

I run a game that renders its own mouse pointer (that has low FPS), so the X cursor is hidden.

I need to force the X cursor to show above the application self rendered cursor.
That way I know where the mouse precisely is so I can wait there for the application mouse pointer to be rendered (even if it renders with a displacement).

OBS.: I am using JWM, so there is no Gnome, Compiz/Unity or KDE at :1

*Failed Attempts:*

- `DISPLAY=:1 xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr` #trying to unhide the mouse pointer or to change its graphics so it show up again
- `xinput set-prop "A4Tech USB Mouse" "Device Enabled" 1` #but the mouse is already enabled there so did not work... (from this [tip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/disable-mouse-not-touchpad-in-xorg-while-idle))