# Prevent the mouse to wake up display

Tags: kde, input, screen-lock

I set my displays to sleep with `xset dpms force off` after locking the screen with kscreenlock. This is great, the displays wake up when the mouse is moved (by me, air, the cat). I'd like to set it in a way that only the keyboards can wake up the screens again.

Is there some way to do this for the KDE screen locker or in general?

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/301742/dont-let-the-mouse-wake-up-displays-from-standby

Comment: It is not a duplicate - the answers overlap, but the other question is not about putting the display to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

First use xinput list to get the device ID for your mouse, and then use

```
xinput --set-prop [ID#] "Device Enabled" "0"
```

and

```
xinput --set-prop [ID#] "Device Enabled" "1"
```

to disable and enable the mouse.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/disable-mouse-not-touchpad-in-xorg-while-idle)

Comment: I wrote a short script using this advice and the OP's `xset xdpms force off`, bound it to a key using `xbindkeys`. I just wanted to note something that took me a while to realize: xbindkeys lets you bind a command to keyrelease, via a virtual "release" modifier: `(xbindkey '(release Scroll_Lock) "my-x11-sleep-script")`. With an ordinary binding the keyrelease would wake up the display again.